# Строка -> Объект PHP

Tags: ооп, php

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, имеется строка (Например, "Start"), необходимо создать объект класса с помощью строки(названия класса), чтобы получилось как-то так (new Start).

```
$sobj = "Start";
$obj = // Какие-то преобразования, чтобы на выходе был Объект Класса Start (new Start)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы об этом?

```
$model='Post';
$models=new $model();
```